# Merge nested array elements

Tags: php, arrays

How can I turn this array result;

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'processed' => int 7
      'committed' => int 0
      'merged' => int 6
      'updated' => int 0
      'skipped' => int 1
      'ids' => 
        array (size=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45c7' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45c9' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45ca' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45cb' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45cc' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644bb0e6df8a148b45cd' => string 'merged' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'processed' => int 6
      'committed' => int 0
      'merged' => int 4
      'updated' => int 0
      'skipped' => int 2
      'ids' => 
        array (size=5)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4574' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4575' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4576' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4578' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4579' => string 'skipped' (length=7)
```

In to something like this;

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'processed' => int 13
      'committed' => int 0
      'merged' => int 12
      'updated' => int 0
      'skipped' => int 1
      'ids' => 
        array (size=13)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45c7' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45c9' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45ca' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45cb' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644ab0e6df8a148b45cc' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644bb0e6df8a148b45cd' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4574' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4575' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4576' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4578' => string 'merged' (length=6)
          '57ff644cb0e6df98148b4579' => string 'skipped' (length=7)
```

Like a merge on each element.

I have tried;

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $new = array_merge_recursive($blah[$key]);
}
```

And a few other convoluted approaches but I can't get it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `array_reduce` like:

```
$finalArray = array_reduce($myArray, function($carry, $item) {

    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($carry[$key])) {
            $carry[$key] = $value;
            continue;
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $carry[$key] = array_merge($carry[$key], $value);
        } else {
            $carry[$key] += $value;
        }
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Comment: can't get my had around what you have done here yet.. but it seems to work perfectly